# React Native Navigation - Redux Integration with "react-native-navigation": "^6.8.0",

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I am trying to setup react native navigation v6 with redux. In the react native navigation docs I can successfully set up my navigation and it works fine without redux added.
I have followed this [link](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/component) but i can't get successful result, so anyone kindly share some workable example for redux integration.